# Limit to Infinity Rational func

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Please, I'm trying to prove that $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{2x-1}{x-3}=2^-$. So far I did $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{2x-1}{x-3}=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{2-\frac{1}{x}}{1-\frac{3}{x}}$ ... so if $x\rightarrow-\infty$ the numerator is $2+\epsilon$ and the denominator is $1+\delta$. How can I prove that this quotient is less than 2? Again, the limit is ok. It equals 2, but why $2^-$?

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is positive, we have $1/(2y)<3/y$ because $1/2<3$. As a result, $1+1/(2y)<1+3/y$, and so ${1+1/(2y)\over 1+3/y}<1$.  Because $x$ in the limit is negative, we thus have ${1-1/(2x)\over 1-3/x}<1$.  Multiply by $2$ to get the desired inequality
$$\frac{2-1/x}{1-3/x}<2$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{2x-1}{x-3}=\frac{2-\frac{1}{x}}{1-\frac{3}{x}}$$

If $x<0$, then both the numerator and the denominator are positive, and $-\frac{1}{x}<-\frac{6}{x}$, so: $$<\frac{2-\frac{6}{x}}{1-\frac{3}{x}}=2$$